# Need reference for $\phi(Z)=Z'$ if and only if $\Phi: \operatorname{Prim}(Z')\to \operatorname{Prim}(Z)$ is injective

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^{\ast}$-algebras with centers $Z$ and $Z'$ respectively. Let $\phi:A \to B$ be surjective $C^{\ast}$-morphism. Then

> $\phi(Z)=Z'$ if and only if the map $\Phi: \operatorname{Prim}(Z') \to \operatorname{Prim}(Z)$ defined as $\Phi(J) = \phi^{-1}(J)$ is injective.

Can someone please give me reference for the above result?

The above result is mentioned without proof in the paper titled [On the homomorphic image of Center of $C^{\ast}$-algebras](https://doi.org/10.7146/math.scand.a-11040) by Vesterstrom.

Comment: Which parts of this have you been able to prove yourself? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, something looks wrong with your notation. What is $\tilde{\phi\vert_Z}$ supposed to be?

Comment: @YemonChoi: I got confused with the proof. Could not get much idea of the proof. I'm trying it. Regarding your second comment: fixed notation

Comment: The map $\tilde \phi$ isn't even well-defined. Sure, $\phi^{-1}(J)$ is a two-sided closed ideal, but will in general not be primitive (even when $J$ is). The primitive ideal space is not a functorial invariant for $C^\ast$-algebras, only in the commutative case.

Comment: @JamieGabe: I have fixed the notations.

Comment: The map $\Phi$ is not well-defined. Take The unital embedding $\mathbb C \oplus \mathbb C \to M_2(\mathbb C)$ as a counter example.

Comment: Argh.  Sorry.  I tried to correct the definition, and I'm not sure I've helped.  I'll leave it up to @MathLover to try to be a little more precise about what exactly is meant.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Probably I am missing something from the linked paper. The exact result is mentioned in Proposition $1$ of the linked paper.

Comment: The linked paper has an important condition which is missing from the question: $\phi$ is supposed to be a _surjective_ $*$-homomorphism!  This takes care of Jamie Gabe's objection (without $\phi$ being surjective, indeed $\Phi$ makes no sense).  I am following [Blackadar's book](https://packpages.unr.edu/media/1224/cycr.pdf), II.6.5.4, if $J=\ker\phi$ then $B\cong A/J$ and $\newcommand{\prim}{\operatorname{Prim}}\prim(A/J) \cong \{K\in\prim(A) : J\subseteq K \}$.  I think to understand Proposition 1 you'll need to know about the Dauns-Hofman Theorem.

Comment: @MatthewDaws: Sorry, my bad. Do you know about any reference where the proof is given?

Comment: The restated version of the question finally makes sense (it would have saved everyone time if a link to the relevant paper had been posted in the original question). Without claiming to immediately see a full proof, it should be noted that fo a commutative ${\rm C}^*$-algebra primitive ideals are the same as maximal ideals, and indeed the primitive ideal space corresponds naturally to the Gelfand spectrum. So the map $\Phi$ admits a very concrete description

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is a theorem about commutative unital C$^*$-algebras (Vesterstrom also has a blanket assumption that $A$ and $B$ are unital).

We have a map $\phi: Z\to Z'$. So $\phi(Z)$ is a C$^*$-subalgebra of $Z'$, and $\phi(Z)=Z'$ if and only if $\phi(Z)$ separates the points of ${\rm Prim}(Z')$. For $J\in{\rm Prim}(Z')$, $\Phi(J)=\phi^{-1}(J)=\{ z\in Z: \phi(z)\in J\}$.

Hence for $J_1, J_2\in{\rm Prim}(Z')$, $\Phi(J_1)=\Phi(J_2)$ if and only if for all $z\in Z$, $\phi(z)\in J_1\Leftrightarrow \phi(z)\in J_2$, and this condition holds if and only if $\phi(Z)$ fails to separate $J_1$ and $J_2$. Thus $\phi$ is surjective if and only if $\Phi$ is injective.

Comment: Sorry where did you use the fact that $A$ and $B$ are unital $C^{\ast}-$ algebras?

Comment: I am not sure that I did, but Vesterstrom has it, so I felt safer with that hypothesis. In the non-unital case, the Stone-Weierstrass theorem requires "separates the points and vanishes nowhere", if I remember, so perhaps I did use it in line 2 of the second para.